# ExpressJS : Proper way to access or declare an environment variable in client/index.html?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm currently learning and toying with Node.js and Express.js and I was wondering what is the proper or most accurate way to use/access a variable depending on environment ( production|development|test ) in client/index.html ?
Typically I would like to use a different Google Analytics code in production and in development environment.

Currently I'm going to investigate/test two solutions :

1. using grunt to inject relevant code in client/index.html
2. using a variable set in /server/config/environment/[production|development|test].js

Is there another options and which one is most appropriate way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are equal, but the second is a bit easier to maintain. You can also pass this value as a URL param in DEV mode (e.g. ?code=123) and skip in production for using a hardcoded constant.